# Commerce 2: How to get the tax amount of a line item, or the line item subtotal without taxes?

Tags: tax

In Craft Commerce 1 we could get the tax amount for a line item by using

```
lineItem.tax
```

Now, in Craft Commerce 2, this always returns 0. How can I get a line item's (or variant's) tax amount, or subtotal without taxes, using twig?

EDIT: on top of that, the suggested method for getting a cart's total tax:

```
getAdjustmentsTotalByType('tax')
```

also returns 0, no matter whether there are tax adjustments.

EDIT 2: Following Robin Schambach's comment, when the tax amount is included in the price, passing 'true' as second option is necessary:

```
getAdjustmentsTotalByType('tax', true)
```

This returns the tax amount from the order or the lineItem, thanks Robin!

Comment: Do you include your tax rate? If so you need to do `lineItem.getAdjustmentsTotalByType('tax', true)`